# DropdownList in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, cascadingdropdown

I need to put 2 cascading dropdownlists on the home page in SharePoint 2010. 
The data have to be populated from the Sharepoint List in both the dropdownlists. I know it can be done easily on InfoPath forms but is there a way to have this functionality on the Webpage as we have in asp.net websites.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by Jquery Library for Sharepoint Web Services
Please refer the link :- 
[Click Here](http://www.sharepointbinder.com/1/post/2012/09/sharepoint-cascading-filtering-dropdowns-using-jquery.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the data to a hidden field and then using JavaScript bind it to the dropdowns this is what we did in our project where it was taking too long to bind it on postback.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with JavaScript, and there are several libraries that can help you :

- [SharepointPlus](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/)
- [SP Services](http://spservices.codeplex.com/)
- [PocketSOAP](http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2013/05/28/teaser-pocketsoap-an-ultra-lightweight-library-to-interact-with-sharepoint-soap-services/)

Answer (score 0):

spcascade.org provides best free solution which support multi level dropdown list with no limits.
It is javascript/jquery based solution with no page refreshes and involves only one look up list for multiple columns.
Saves data in single line text instead of typical Ids that are used by typical look up columns.
Very easy to use syntax too!

http://www.spcascade.org